# How to remove a structure from an array of structures and correctly overwrite a file using fwrite()

Tags: c, arrays, file, structure, fwrite

**Hi everyone I'm new to C. I had to create a "library" where I can store some books and make some changes on them (add a book, remove a book or change it) using an array of structures, then I have to save it in a file.**

The problem is that it should be possible to remove a book and overwrite the changes in the file opened in "r+b" mode using the fwrite() function.

At first I read from the file to the array of structures and count the number of books in it using fread(), then after I remove a book I scroll the structures down and I assign an empty structure to the last structure.

Ex.

- Book1
- Book2
- Book3

After removing "Book2" and scrolling down the structures:

- Book1
- Book3
- Book3

After assigning an empty structure to the last one that has been read:

- Book1
- Book3
- Random_Stuff

Then I save only the first two structures to the file and when I read the file I get:

- Book1
- Book3
- Book3

If I overwrite the file with the 3 structures I get:

- Book1
- Book3
- Random_Stuff

And that's reasonable, but how can I overwrite the whole file just with, in this case, the first two structures using fwrite()?

This is my structure

```
typedef struct book {
        char title[MAXTIT];
        char autor[MAXAUT];
        float price;
} info;
```

This is the function to remove a book:

```
void remove_book(info bibl[], int * num) {

// Empty structure to assign to the last structure after the removal
info empty;

char title[256];

puts("Enter the title of the book you want to remove:");
read(title, 256);

// Scrolling down the structures to cover the removed one
for (int i = 0 ; i < *num ; i++)
    if (strcmp(title, bibl[i].title) == 0) {
        for (int index = i ; index < *num ; index++)
            bibl[index] = bibl[index + 1];
        bibl[*num] = empty;
        (*num)--;
        break;
    }

for (int index = 0 ; index < *num ; index++)
    printf("%s, autor: %s, price: %.2f €\n", bibl[index].title, bibl[index].autor, bibl[index].price);
}
```

This is the full code (just in case):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAXTIT  40          // Maximum lenght of the title
#define MAXAUT  40          // Maximum lenght of the name of the autor
#define MAXBOOK 10          // Maximum number of books

typedef struct book {
        char title[MAXTIT];
        char autor[MAXAUT];
        float price;
} info;

int size = sizeof(info);
int counter = 0;
int counterp;
FILE * fp;
char file_name[64];

int menu(void);
void add_book(info [], int *);
void remove_book(info [], int *);
void modify_book(info [], int);
void input(info [], int *, int *);
char *read(char *, int);

int main(void) {

info bibl[MAXBOOK];
int index, choice;

puts("Please, enter the file to be read:");
read(file_name, 64);

// If returns a NULL pointer puts an error message and ends the program
if (!(fp = fopen(file_name, "r+b"))) {
    fprintf(stderr, "An error occurred while trying to open \"%s\".", file_name);
    exit(1);
}

// Read the content of the file
input(bibl, &counter, &counterp);

    // If the file is empty lets the user add a book
    if (counterp == 0) {
        add_book(bibl, &counter);
        fwrite(&bibl[counterp], size, counter - counterp, fp);

        // If the user added a book shows the content of the file
        if (counter > 0) {
            puts("Updated file content:");
            for (index = 0 ; index < counter ; index++)
                printf("%d) %s, autor: %s, price: %.2f €\n", index + 1, bibl[index].title, bibl[index].autor, bibl[index].price);
            putchar('\n');
        }
    }

    // If there is something in the file lets the user choose between some options (add, remove, modify a book or simply quit)
    if (counter > 0) {

        // Menu returns a value for the switch function
        choice = menu();

        // Repeats the choice until the "Quit" option has been chosen
        while (choice) {

            switch(choice) {

            // First case, reads from the file, adds the book and writes everything in the file
            case 1 :    input(bibl, &counter, &counterp);
                    add_book(bibl, &counter);
                    fwrite(&bibl[counterp], size, counter - counterp, fp);
                    break;

            // Second case, reads from the file, (should) removes the book and overwrites everything in the file
           case 2 : input(bibl, &counter, &counterp);
                    remove_book(bibl, &counter);
                    rewind(fp);                 // Rewind to overwrite the new values in the file
                    fwrite(&bibl[0], size, counterp, fp);
                    break;

            // Third case, reads from the file, modifies the book and overwrites everything in the file
           case 3 : input(bibl, &counter, &counterp);
                    modify_book(bibl, counter);
                    rewind(fp);                 // Same as before
                    fwrite(&bibl[0], size, counter, fp);
                    break;

            // Forth case, quits the menu
           case 4 : break;

            // Should never activate but I put it in case I'd like to modify something in the menu ecc...
          default : fputs("You entered wrong data!", stderr);
                    break;

          }

        // If a change has been made shows the new content
        if (choice >= 1 && choice <= 3) {
            puts("Updated file content:");

            for (index = 0 ; index < counter ; index++)
                printf("%d) %s, autor: %s, price: %.2f €\n", index + 1, bibl[index].title, bibl[index].autor, bibl[index].price);

            putchar('\n');
        }

        // Exit the loop in case of "Quit" option
        if (choice == 4)
            break;

        choice = menu();
    }

} else
    puts("No books? What a pity!");

// If fclose() != NULL, an error occurred
if (fclose(fp))
    fprintf(stderr, "An error occurred while trying to close \"%s\".", file_name);

puts("Ending process...");

return 0;
}

// Function that shows the options of the menu
int menu(void) {

int num;

puts("Choose between:\n1) Add a book\n2) Remove book\n3) Modify a book\n4) Quit");

while (scanf("%d", &num) != 1 || num < 1 || num > 4)
    puts("Choice between:\n1) Add a book\n2) Remove book\n3) Modify a book\n4) Quit");

while (getchar() != '\n');

return num;
}

// Function used to add a book to the file (works fine)
void add_book(info bibl[], int * num) {

int index;
bool flag = false;

puts("Please, enter a new title ([enter] at the start of the line ends the process):");

while (*num < MAXBOOK && read(bibl[*num].title, MAXTIT) && bibl[*num].title[0] != '\0') {

    puts("Now enter the autor.");
    read(bibl[*num].autor, MAXAUT);

    for (index = 0 ; index < *num ; index++)
        if (strcmp(bibl[index].title, bibl[*num].title) == 0 && strcmp(bibl[index].autor, bibl[*num].autor) == 0) {
            puts("This book is already in your library.");
            puts("Please, enter a new title ([enter] at the start of the line ends the process):");
            flag = true;
            break;
        }

    if (flag)
        continue;

    puts("And finally enter the price.");
    scanf("%f", &bibl[(*num)++].price);

    while (getchar() != '\n');

    if (*num < MAXBOOK)
        puts("\nPlease, enter a new title ([enter] at the start of the line ends the process):");
    }
}

// Function that should work and do what it's meant to do but it doesn't for I don't know what reason
void remove_book(info bibl[], int * num) {

// Empty structure to assign to the last structure after the removal
info empty;

char title[256];

puts("Enter the title of the book you want to remove:");
read(title, 256);

// Scrolling down the structures to cover the removed one
for (int i = 0 ; i < *num ; i++)
    if (strcmp(title, bibl[i].title) == 0) {
        for (int index = i ; index < *num ; index++)
            bibl[index] = bibl[index + 1];
        bibl[*num] = empty;
        (*num)--;
        break;
    }

for (int index = 0 ; index < *num ; index++)
    printf("%s, autor: %s, price: %.2f €\n", bibl[index].title, bibl[index].autor, bibl[index].price);
}

// Function used to change a book's informations
void modify_book(info bibl[], int num) {

    char title[256];
    int choice;

    puts("Enter the title of the book you want to modify:");
    read(title, 256);

    puts("Choose what you want to modify:\n1) Title\n2) Autor\n3) Price\n4) Everything");
    while(scanf("%d", &choice) != 1 || choice < 1 || choice > 4)
        puts("Choose what you want to modify:\n1) Title\n2) Autor\n3) Price\n4) Everything");

    while (getchar() != '\n');

    for (int i = 0 ; i < num ; i++) {
        if (strcmp(title, bibl[i].title) == 0) {

            switch (choice) {


            case 1 :    puts("Please, enter the new title of the book:");
                        read(bibl[i].title, MAXTIT);
                        break;

            case 2 :    puts("Enter the new autor of the book:");
                        read(bibl[i].autor, MAXAUT);
                        break;

            case 3 :    puts("Enter the new price:");
                        scanf("%f", &bibl[i].price);
                        while (getchar() != '\n');
                        break;

            case 4 :    puts("Please, enter the title of the book:");
                        read(bibl[i].title, MAXTIT);
                        puts("Now enter the autor of the book:");
                        read(bibl[i].autor, MAXAUT);
                        puts("And finally its cost:");
                        scanf("%f", &bibl[i].price);
                        while (getchar() != '\n');
                        break;

            default :   break;

            }

            break;
        }
    }

    for (int index = 0 ; index < num ; index++)
        printf("%s, autor: %s, price: %.2f €\n", bibl[index].title, bibl[index].autor, bibl[index].price);
}

// Function that reads from the file in which we are saving the structures
void input(info bibl[], int * counter, int * counterp) {

    *counter = 0;
    rewind(fp);

    while (*counter < MAXBOOK && fread(&bibl[*counter], size, 1, fp) == 1) {

        if (*counter == 0)
            printf("Actual content of the file \"%s\":\n", file_name);

        printf("%d) %s by %s: %.2f €\n", *counter + 1, bibl[*counter].title, bibl[*counter].autor, bibl[*counter].price);
        (*counter)++;
    }

    if (*counter > 0 && *counter < MAXBOOK)
        putchar('\n');

    *counterp = *counter;
    if (*counter == MAXBOOK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "The file \"%s\" is full.", file_name);
        exit(1);
    }
}

// Better alternative for gets()
char *read(char * str, int len) {

    char * res, * here;

    if (res = fgets(str, len, stdin))
        if (here = strchr(str, '\n'))
            *here = '\0';
        else
            while (getchar() != '\n');

    return res;
}
```

Comment: Fyi, in `remove_book`, your inner-for condition `index <= (*num) - 1 ` - is not right. That's the same as `index < (*num)` which is what you want to *avoid*. That should be strictly-less-than.

Comment: I could, but unfortunately the exercise says I have to do this with only one file open and only in "r+b" mode to overwrite the past content :/ Anyway, thanks a lot @user3121023

Comment: @WhozCraig You're right, I'm going to correct it, thanks :)

Comment: I will keep the post in case some pieces of the code will be found useful by someone, for example the read() function works well instead of gets() which is unsafe but still used by many people :D

Comment: It looks like this question was answered by editing it to overwrite the question with an answer. We don't do that here, since it leaves us an answer with no question. Please post a summary of the solution in the answer box below - self-answered questions are warmly welcomed here.